# Adicionar vários projetos a uma solução DOTNET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, ddd

Estou criando um projeto do 0 e configurando ele, estou criando um projeto usando DOTNET 6 e criando a estrutura por cli no ubuntu (nunca tinha usado sem ser no VS).

eu criei minha solução normalmente, e estou com outras bibliotecas de classes, como uma lib class para API, DOMAIN, etc.

Executando o comando: `dotnet sln add (ls -r **/*.csproj)` eu obtenho o erro: `bash: number expected`

Há alguma outra forma de fazer as referencias?

vi em diversos lugares que o comando: `dotnet sln add (ls -r **/*.csproj)` resolveria o problema das referencias na solução, porém não achei em nenhum lugar o erro que eu estou tendo. Eu estou tentando rodar esse comando, porém o bash me retorna: `bash: number expected`

Comment: É Windows, Linux ou macOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro da pasta onde está a solução, no terminal digite:

dotnet sln add "caminho"

o caminho precisa conter todo o path até o csproj

Exemplo:

dotnet sln add ./source/APIExemplo.Domain/APIExemplo.Domain.csproj

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).